# views_query_alter never called

Tags: views

I want to alter a query for sorting a field. I read the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7), it says

> This hook should be placed in MODULENAME.views.inc and it will be
>   auto-loaded. MODULENAME.views.inc must be in the directory specified
>   by the 'path' key returned by MODULENAME_views_api(), or the same
>   directory as the .module file, if 'path' is unspecified.

I used to implement all hooks inside my sites/default/realia/template.php so I first went stright and implemented the hook in sites/default/realaia/template.php which obviously didnt work.

```
function realia_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
    print "<h1>I am in alter query</h1>";
    var_dump($query);
}
```

After reading doc carefully which says the hook needs to be placed inside the specific file and in a specific place I totally feel lost. Because I don't see any .module file in my sites/default/themes/realia. This is where my all files provided by realia (3rd party) are placed there is only .info file but no .module file.

There are also other related modules inside sites/all/modules/realia but looks like this folder is not a module itself becuse there are no .info or .module files inside the root but subfolders/modules has it. I went and created a file reala_submodule.views.inc with the implementation and placed one in each of the modules but I still dont see it really got executed ever.

Of course I did drush cc all every time whenever I doubted there could be caching issue. I will have followup questions related sorting once I get this implementation working. Please help.

Comment: You need to [write your own module](https://drupal.org/developing/modules) for this, is that the bit of info you're missing?

Comment: I created a new module with .info, .module and mymodule.views.inc with the hook implementation. I dont see its called ever (the debug statements are never rendered on browser)

Comment: Please do not change meaning of a question once it got answers...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe  reason can be if you use Search API module, in this case hook_search_api_views_query_alter will work instead

[link 1](https://www.drupal.org/node/2179003)
[link 2](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/146704/why-view-is-not-firing-hook-views-query-alter)

I have the same problem now and after some search find that when search API module enabled  [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) not worked.

Comment: Thanks a billion, I had been banging my head figuring out why hook views query alter is not invoking :)

Comment: @InspiredCoder you're very welcome. thanks for your comment. I feel good when I saw my answer help another guy ^__^

Answer (score 2):

It's not called because it's too late to call it from theme layer. You should call it from a module.

Comment: please check my updated question. I implemented query alter in new module. But wondering why its not called

Comment: Put it in the module body, rather than in another file. See if it works there.

Comment: That did the trick. Can you please help me understand why it didnt worked in the way docs said? I have a separate post [here] (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/104985/trying-to-understand-hook-views-query-alter-for-sorting)

Comment: When you add an inc file, you should include it in a module or in an inf file. Sometimes you don't. But in this case, obviosly, the file was not getting called.