# trying to understand hook_views_query_alter for sorting

Tags: views

My requirement is to sort the nodes with a "condition" based on whether a field called myfield has value in it or not and then by date created. That means, show nodes first if a field has value and then by datecreated.

its something like this sql query

```
select field1,
       datecreated,
       if(isnull(myfield,1),1,0) hasvalue

from table
order by hasvalue asc, datecreated desc
```

For doing this I learnt that I need to create a module called tdyards and implemented tdyards_views_query_alter in tdyards.views.inc with this code in it and enabled the module.

```
<?php

function tdyards_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
    print "<h1>I am in tdyards alter query</h1>";
    var_dump($query);
    die(); 
}
```

I was expecting this pileup my screen with the dump but it seems like it is never called this function. Am I missing anything else here? If my guess is correct it must call this for each and every view because my implementation doesn not have any condition

Comment: Hello. Could you edit your question's title? Body seems pretty OK, but title looks like you are looking for tutorials etc and that's explicitly off-topic, so it creates impression you don't want.

Comment: have you cleared your caches since creating this function?  if not, drupal won't know to look for it.

Comment: yes sir. its weird that  Alexei Rayu suggestion in my early post did the trick. I had to add it in .module for it to work. Looking for someone to help me understand this why and how